# Mathematical Significance of Sum of Elements of a Vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

While working on a research problem of mine I noticed that I had to do the sum of the elements of a vector multiple times. I don't have a sound background in mathematics. So, I wanted to ask is there any mathematical significance of the sum of the elements of a vector.

And by the sum of the elements of a vector, I do not mean the sum of the magnitudes.

I want to know what does this expression $\sum_i v_i$ signify?? I figured out that I can also write it as $<\textbf{1},\textbf{v}>$. Is there anything that this expression indicates or signifies?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Yes, $\langle {\bf 1},v \rangle$ is correct. If all $v_i \geq 0$, this is also the $L1$-norm. As to what it signifies, that depends on the context of course.  Note that it depends on your choice of basis; however it's preserved by stochastic transformations.

Comment: There's the geometric interpretation of the dot product. The sum encodes data about how "similar" the vector is to $\mathbf{1}$.